# Open image in new window...Is it possible without picture being opened in a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, window.open

I've been wondering if there is any way to open a .png pictue separately from the main window (window.open) but without the dreadful browser appearance, I would like to see only the image??

Thank you,

Andraz.

Comment: Thanks guys but it's not what I've been trying to do. Let me try to explain it a little bit better. I want to open an image separately from my main page but I DON'T want it to open in a new browser window because I would only like to see the image and not the image + browser. The open.window function opens new browser window, i would like to see it without (as a sort of gadget or something). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need the window.open function. You can pass a bunch of paameters into that to tell it to not show the address ar, toolbar, status bar, etc etc

You'd just neec to set the href/document source as the png file.

Comment: Note, however, that modern browsers limit your options with respect to what you can do with the newly opened window. For instance, Firefox won't let you hide the address bar (unless the user allows that in the settings).

Comment: +1 Michal, I didn't know that, it's been a while since I actually used window.open ;)

Answer (score 1):

Anthony is correct.

```
    window.open ("www.yoururl.com","mywindow","status=1");
```

you can use:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function poponload()
    {
         testwindow = window.open("www.yoururl.com", "mywindow","location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=700,height=500");
         testwindow.moveTo(0, 0);
    }
   </script>

<body onload="javascript: poponload()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at a plugin like [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) which can show an image in the current window, quite nicely. Very easy to implement :)

If you want it in a new window without the toolbars and so on, you should look for [documentation on window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) and look at the 3rd parameter it takes.